# Как избавиться от ошибки "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" при отправке http запроса? httpclietn

Tags: java, веб-программирование, http, requests, https

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая отправляет http(s) запросы на определенный url с определенным методом.
При попытке отправить запрос на хост yandex.ru - все работает отлично.
Если меняю хост, например, на pikabu.ru - вылетает длинная ошибка, часть её:
"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
Из-за чего так происходит?

Код:

```
package MyAutoCheck;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class HTTP_REQ {
    public void sendReq(String url) throws IOException {
        try (
                CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
                CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        ) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream data = entity.getContent();
                System.out.println("Date: " + data);
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (Header header: response.getAllHeaders()) {
                System.out.println(header.getName() + " : " + header.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Protocol version: " + response.getProtocolVersion());
            System.out.println("Status code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("Response phrase: " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            System.out.println("Status line: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
        } catch (Throwable cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, клиент не смог проверить сертификат. Добавьте опцию `-Djavax.net.debug=all` при запуске программы, в консоль будет выведен подробный лог всего процесса и в том числе какая именно проверка какого сертификата не прошла.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Куда нужно добавить эту опцию? (Я пишу в intellij idea)

Comment: В Run Configuration для запуска программы есть опции JVM https://stackoverflow.com/q/50938383/2231972